How to remove white background on kivy app icon?
Kivy app icon is not filling the entire space designed for It.
I am not English fluent, but I will describe my problem as best as I can. I am using an icon with 480 x 320 of size and It works fine on the smartphone, but instead of occupying the entire space, the icon is being reduced to approximatelly 50% of the size. The rest is being occupied by a white background. How do I do to put the icon for occupying the entire space?
The only change I made in spec file related to the icon was:
icon.filename = directory_name/icon_name.png

If you have english problems you can always to use toola as reverso context that help a lot to translate in context that normally is more acurated

Please post a [mcve].

There are in fact two ways to add icons for kivy apps. The quick one that you used which is simple but does not allow resize of the icon and an adaptative one which works as follows.
You have to edit the following lines of the buildozer.spec file instead :
# (str) Adaptive icon of the application (used if Android API level is 26+ at runtime)
icon.adaptive_foreground.filename = ./resources/ic_launcher.png
icon.adaptive_background.filename = ./resources/ic_launcher_background.png

The two images must be defined as explained on this page : https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/icon_design_adaptive
Both images should have the same size, I recommend using 512x512.
The foreground should have content only in the center square of dimension 312x312 (with recommended dimension).

I will do only a correction in your comment, It's not presplash image,  It's Icon image, but anyway I already tried It and usually the image used is even smaller, something like 32x32. If somebody sucessed to do It with kivy, please, tell me the size of image used.

@LeonardoTiago you are right, my bad. I thought it was about presplash. I know also the procedure for icons so I have edited my comment.

@LeonardoTiago I noticed a vote up on the answer, could you please also accept the answer if it suits you?
